# What exports.execute does here

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm facing a code that has this:

```
exports.execute = function(request, response){
   // Code here
}
```

As far as I can go, `function(req, res)` allows to get a `http request` and its `response`, but what is the meaning by doing all of this? I've tried to search info but couldn't find enything.

I have to highlight that today is my 2nd day with `.js`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is being exported with a named export 'execute'.
You can import it in other files `const { execute } = require('filepath')`

look here
https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/